# How to connect to Microsoft Dynamic 365 using SDK using .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: dynamics-crm, asp.net-core-3.1, dynamic365

How can we perform CRUD operations in custom entity in Dynamic 365 using SDK?

Comment: The CRM SDK is still not officially available for anything newer than .NET 4.6.2 : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies/ . There is a "replacement" library for .NET Core, but it's still in preview stage and **NOT** officially released: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client/

Comment: @Kaishu Have you got any solution on this ?

Comment: @DnyaneshSurya Yes - Using HttpClient as per this solution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/enhanced-quick-start